# What is the easiest way to set all attributes (except id, created_at, updated_at) of an ActiveRecord object to nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the easiest way to set all attributes (except id, created_at, updated_at) of an ActiveRecord object to nil?

Comment: Honestly this seems to be a very special case, could you explain a bit why this is required - maybe, there's a better solution. In the meantime, check out my answer.

Comment: Yeah I know it's a bit strange, but trust me it was necessary. Thanks for your answer, worked great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an array called `attribute_names` on the model, which does include all attributes, so use reject to filter attributes:

```
class Model < AR::Base
  def nilify_attributes!(except = nil)
    except ||= %w{id created_at updated_at}
    attribute_names.reject { |attr| except.include?(attr) }.each { |attr| self[attr] = nil }
  end
end
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-attribute_names

Comment: Is this still valid for Rails 4.2?

Comment: Looks like yes, the method `attribute_names` is still present.

Answer (score 6):

If it's a one-time thing, you could do this in the controller:

```
@record.update_attributes(Hash[*@record.attributes.except('created_at','updated_at','id').map { |a| [a.first, nil] }.flatten])
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered already. I also came across the same situation that brought up another solution.

```
record.dup.attributes.keep_if{|k,v| !v.nil?}
```

Here record is the active record object.

Comment: This worked for me, and I am using Rails 4.2. One liners are great.

Comment: This does the opposite but even if you'd use `v.nil?` (without bang) there's a difference between removing values from a hash and explicitly setting attributes of an object to `nil`. This does the former, the question was about the latter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.column_names.map { |col| [col, nil] }.to_h.except(*[attrs_to_except])
```

Comment: It's good practice on StackOverflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work.

Comment: The question is about to set the attrs and here is the best way to do it if you want all attrs to be nil except :id then just simply except it.