# How to create a record in database using a hash which is created from another record in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am having two rails systems, on one system I created a record using active record. Now I am converting that object to a Hash using attributes method like this `user_hash = @user.attributes` and sending it to other rails system.
Now I want to create user record on this system with this hash. The problem I am facing is that "id" field in database, how to override that field.
is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613057/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-set-all-attributes-except-id-created-at-updated-at

Comment: sorry but in that its except id, here I want to do it with id.

Comment: Do you want to set the `id` in the  `user_hash` as the id of new record created in your other system?

Comment: I have complete user hash including id, I want to create a User with this hash in other system. with exactly same user details and id, anyway thanks i got a solution from Arup..:)

Answer (score 1):

you can use clone also

```
# rails < 3.1
new_record = old_record.clone

#rails >= 3.1
new_record = old_record.dup
```

Returns a clone of the record that hasn’t been assigned an `id` yet and is treated as a new record.

Comment: how to do it in other system, as I am having two separate systems.?

Comment: @ritzz.soni Is your system is a legacy one ?

Comment: @ritzz.soni I got confused.. so I deleted my answer. Please clarify in your question, what is the _goal_ ?

Comment: @ritzz.soni glad to know.. But I wouldn't open it again! It is _gone gone_.. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit i got the point..so no worries..anyway thanks..:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80248/discussion-between-ritzz-soni-and-arup-rakshit).

Answer (score 0):

```
user_hash = @user.attributes
user_hash = ["id", "created_at", "updated_at"].each{ |k| user_hash.delete(k) }
```